# Inverse on a restricted domain

Tags: functions, inverse

I have a function, whose domain is [0,1]. The function is

```
f = Piecewise[{{Exp[-β * (-Log[#])^α], 0 < # <= 1}}, #]&
```

with `β > 0` and `α > 0`

(side note: is this the best way of defining the function such that it's `Exp[-β * (-Log[#])^α]` on (0,1] and 0 at 0?)

I would now like to use the inverse of this function, which I'm pretty sure exists (and is `E^(-(-1)^((1/α)) β^(-1/α) Log[w]^(1/α))`). However,

```
InverseFunction[f]
```

simply returns the call and not the actual inverse.

At this point I'm not sure whether it's my lousy *Mathematica* skills that keep me from getting the correct inverse or whether there's something in the math that I've neglected to consider. What am I doing wrong? How do I tell *Mathematica* to just find the inverse on [0,1] and how do I tell it that both parameters are positive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I would restrict the domain of the inverse after inverting it, as follows

```
invf = InverseFunction[Exp[-β (-Log[#])^α] &]
(* E^(-(-1)^((1/α)) β^(-1/α) Log[#1]^(1/α))& *)

Piecewise[{{E^(-(-1)^((1/α)) β^(-1/α) Log[#1]^(1/α)), 0 < # <= 1}}, #]&
```

or, a little more programmatically

```
With[{f = invf[[1]], Piecewise[{{f, 0 < # <= 1}}, #]&]
```

where the `With` gets around the `HoldAll` attribute of `Function`. Although, this works, too:

```
Piecewise[{{invf[#], 0 < # <= 1}}, #]&
```